# How can I redraw an Anko frameLayout when my model changes?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I have an [Anko component](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) where I create my view with some code like this:

```
override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<T>) = with(ui) {
    frameLayout {
        var imgView = imageView(R.drawable.ic_1).lparams {
            horizontalMargin = ...
            topMargin = ...
            width = ...
            height = ...
        }
        imgView.backgroundColor = gameModel.colour
    }
}
```

The background of my `imgView` depends on a colour in my model.

Let's imagine I update my model elsewhere.  How do I 'refresh' the Anko component UI to reflect the new `gameModel.colour`?  I've never done any `Android` before but it seems one would usually use either `invalidate()` or `requestLayout()` but they don't seem to work.

Comment: In Anko (and classic XML), the layout gets created once and should never be recreated. To change properties of views, you can store references to these views (`imgView` in this case) and change properties when necessary.

Comment: @Miha_x64 Thanks.  ok.  That's what I'm currently doing.  I just wondered if there was another way.